# Por que quando apago ou edito registro da tabela x é removido também da tabela y?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou com um sistema em ***ASP MVC*** com ***C#*** utilizando ***entity framework***.

Tenho a tabela `Pedidos` e `Agenda`.

Na tabela `agenda` tenho uma coluna com o `id` do pedido.

Quando o pedido é cancelado, tenho que remover da tabela `Agenda` para liberar um horário para um novo pedido.

O problema é que quando remove a linha da tabela `Agenda` com o pedido 13(por exemplo), na tabela `pedido` o mesmo é removido também.

Já fiz uma busca e encontrei algo sobre `Cascade` no ***SQL***, mas isso não está ativado.

O que pode ser?

Segue código:

```
 public partial class ifixEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
      : base("name=MyEntities")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Agenda>().HasOptional<Pedido>(s => s.Pedido).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso se chama **Cascade Delete** e é um comportamento padrão do Entity Framework.

Você também pode colocar algumas regras gerais, e não apenas específico por cada model.

**Ex:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
}
```

Assim você remove em todas as models.

Comment: Obrigado, só confirmando: desse modo é deletado somente de 1 tabela?

Comment: exato...porém esse comportamtento o entity faz pq ele acha que o outro registro irá ficar orfão, então verifique se realmente precisa manter o outro dado, é claro que ele apenas 'acha' vc que deve decidir.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!! sim preciso que seja removido somente de 1 tabela, para manter histórico de pedidos no sistema.

Answer (score 2):

exemplo para remover cascade delete

```
public class SchoolContext<: DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext():base("MySchool")
    {
                }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

fonte: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Srs, só informando tentei usar as duas configurações mas continua sendo removido de ambas as tabelas.

Comment: @RonaldoPeres coloca seu codigo ai na pergunta